# strange behavior of C++ downcasting on object

Tags: c++, class, struct, variable-assignment, downcast

i ran the code below to assign parent portion of objet to child object.
but as described inline, c style downcast behaves something unexpected.
what happen there? please refer to the comment below.

```
    struct A {
    public:
        int i{};
        A() { std::cout<<"A constructor called\r\n"; }
        ~A() { std::cout<<"A destructor called\r\n"; }
    };

    struct B : public A {
        B() { std::cout<<"B constructor called\r\n"; }
        ~B() { std::cout<<"B destructor called\r\n"; }
    };

    A a{};
    B b{};
    a.i = 1;
    (A)b = a;  // this code no effect and surprisingly the destructor of A is called.
               // there was no compiler warning (g++ (Ubuntu 11.2.0-7ubuntu2) 11.2.0)
    std::cout<<a.i<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<b.i<<std::endl;
    A& ra = b;
    ra = a;     // A portion of B is initialized as expected
    std::cout<<b.i<<std::endl;
```

---

this code prints as

A constructor called
A constructor called
B constructor called
A destructor called <-- please note here 
1
0
1
B destructor called
A destructor called
A destructor called

Comment: `(A)b` causes a new `A` to be copy constructed see live - https://godbolt.org/z/ox11h76sd . 
 Note the values of `this` are output to enable the tracking object creation / destruction.  I have also commented out the assignment for clarity.

Comment: o.k, c style downcasting on object causes copy construction. that's why the constructor of A is not called. then is this c++ behavior ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

magic is here:
(A)b = a;

what happend is:

1. call A's copy constructor and create a new **[class A object]**. it's a temporary object, and it's destoryed after this statement.
   so print **[A destructor called <-- please note here]**
2. call A's operator= on the temporary object. it's only effect the temporary object instead of original b;

Comment: what i don't understand is why typecasting makes a temporal object. is this expected c++ statement behavior ?

Comment: it's expected;  if you don't want a temp object. you should use pointer or reference. eg:                  (A&)b = a;        if you use (A)b,  you cast b to class A , there must be a new memory block ( temp object ) hold the cast value

Comment: now i understand. but i think the syntax is not intuitive. since other primitive types don't make temporal object when it is casted. thank you for your kind reply.